# Unable to get id value in vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to fetch data from Pixabay api using JavaScript. Currently, I am able to display the api data but I am trying to create a separate page for each image id dynamically. For example, if someone click on one image, it should redirect to a different page called photos.html/id/photoname.

JavaScript Code

```
let editorChoice = document.querySelector('.editorchoice')

async function getImg(){
    let imgData = await fetch('https://pixabay.com/api/?key=12345&editors_choice')
   let imgRaw = await imgData.json()
   console.log(imgRaw)
  let itemData = imgRaw.hits

  //To create <div class="row"> in each row dynamically
  for(let i = 0; i < itemData.length; i++) {
    //Declare item variable and store itemData since itemData has stored api details 
    let item = itemData[i] //i stands for those id starts from 0 in the api. 
    //It won't possible to display image if we don't add i
    let imgId = item.id 
    let imgType = item.type
    let imgPreview = item.previewURL
    let imgTag = item.tags
    let webImgWidth = item.webformatWidth
    let webImgHeight = item.webformatHeight
    let largeSizeImg = item.largeImageURL
    let largeImgWidth = item.imageWidth
    let largeImgHeight = item.imageHeight
    let totalImgView = item.views
    let totalDownloads = item.downloads
    let imgCollections = item.collections
    let imgLikes = item.likes
    let imgUrl = item.pageURL
    
    //Here we are dividing each row into 3 columns. If we want to display 4 columns 
    //in each row, it should be i % 4 === 0
if(i % 3 === 0) {
  editorChoice.innerHTML += `<div class="row">`
}

    editorChoice.innerHTML += `<div class="col-lg-4 card">
    <img id="${imgId}" src="${imgPreview}" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="${imgTag}"/>
    <a href="photos.html?id=${imgId}"><p class="text-center">${imgTag}</p></a>
    </div>`
  }

}
getImg()
```

photos.html

```
 <div class="content-main">
              <div class="container-fluid bg-3 text-center">   
                <div id="imageDetails"></div>

              </div>
            </div>
```

index.html

```
   <div class="container-fluid bg-3 text-center">   
       
        <h3>Editor's Choice</h3><br>

        <div class="editorchoice"> 
      
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You haven't explained what you're trying to add or fix here. You've presented existing code and you've said that you can't "get the ID value" but we don't know what that means specifically.

Comment: Please explain the HTML page more. You dropped the visible HTML code here, but we cannot see the meta of your pages. For example, where is the so-called "JavaScript code" being used? in what page?

Comment: I want to create a separate page to display id value and its details.

Comment: Hi @TalRofe, the javascript code is actually app.js and I have put it at the bottom of the index and photos.html. For index.html,   <div id="imageDetails"></div> is required. Rest are just to adjust the layout. For photos.html, that's just some regular html to express the idea.

Comment: based on what you have provided the only thing I see if that you likely want to wrap your image tag with your a tag so that when you click the image, it will navigate to your photos page.

Comment: Yes exactly and with that particular image details.

Comment: when you click the link does it actually navigate to photos and have the proper id in the url? Based on your last comment it sounds like your issue is reading the photo data on the photos page... in that case you need to provide how you are planning to load the data on that page? Is this using a framework like react that provides routing?

Comment: Yes. You are right @floor. I am trying to achieve it through plain JavaScript only. No framework or library.

Comment: well on your photos page, you will need to dissect the url to get the id and make a ajax call to get the photo data again. Html pages don't share data between them. Another possible solution is storing photo info in local storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you just use simply HTML and JavaScript without any library (React?) or framework (Angular?) the way you'd achieve it is by creating another JavaScript code dedicated for the `photos.html` page.

The idea is to fetch the data of a single image and then show it. Of course in `photos.html` page you don't need all the images data, but only 1 image data.
To fetch the image's data, you need its identifier. The correct way to get it would be by using query parameters in the URL. An example: `xxx.com/photos.html?id=234543554`.

**Photo page "algorithm":**

1. Get the photo identifier
2. Fetch the photo's data by its identifier
3. Display the data you just fetched in any way you want

```js
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const photoId = urlParams.get('id');

async function getImgData(){
    const imgData = await fetch(`https://pixabay.com/api/?key=12345&photoId=${photoId}`); // I don't know your API so you should adjust it..
    const imgRaw = await imgData.json();

    const photoContainer = document.querySelector('#imageDetails');
    photoContainer.innerHTML = imgRaw.id; // I simply just display here the identifier of the photo - of course you could do whatever you want
}

getImgData();
```

From here, you just need to make sure that is your `index.html`, where you show all the images, each images is wrapped by a link (`<a>` element) where once being clicked, user navigates to the `photos.html` page together with `id` query param attached.